# Beta Vector from Scaled PLS Model not Reproducing Predicted Responses

Tags: r, partial-least-squares

I am running R 3.0.2 and using the PLS package to build partial least squares models. The problem I am having is that when I apply feature-scaling to my design matrix the resulting coefficient vector does not reproduce the predicted response values on my training and cross-validation samples. Here is my code:

```
model.train <- cppls(y ~ ., data = data.train, ncomp = 20, scale = TRUE, 
                     validation = "none", weights = w)
yhat.train <- fitted(model.train)
B <- coef(model.train, intercept = TRUE, ncomp = 20)
yhat.cv <- predict(model.train, newdata = data.cv, ncomp = 20, type = "response")
```

If I then take the B vector and multiply by my design matrix, the resulting values do not equal the values generated by the `fitted()` and `predict()` functions; in other words, `Y != BX`. However if I run the exact same code with `scale = FALSE` in the `cppls()` function, `Y = BX`.

My question is whether the `coef()` function is simply failing to re-scale the betas, or if I'm making some error in my routine. I would really like to be able to apply feature-scaling to my design matrix, but I need the correct beta vector as an output. Would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: Gavin, thanks for your feedback. I did not pre-scale the design matrix, but I did apply scaling via the 'scale=TRUE' argument. I assumed (wrongly, it seems) the beta values would be automatically re-scaled for me. Is best practice in this case to re-scale manually, i.e. divide the scaled beta vector by a corresponding SD vector?

Comment: I meant did you scale `X` when computing `Y = BX` by hand? ANyway, you've answered that with what you write later. I'm not familiar enough with Canonical PLS to know if you can just undo the scaling in the manner described in the [stats.se] post I linked to. If it is similar to PLS, then it should be ok to do this as PLS is just a linear regression at heart. Perhaps this would be best on [stats.se]. You could flag it for migration by a moderator?